# Select the value from an associative massive array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get some value from the massive array, and there occured some problem.
I have such array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(23) {
    ["ITEM_ID"]=>
    int(2331)
    ["ITEM_TYPE_ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["CART_ITEM_ID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["SAVED_TYPE_ID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ITEM_NAME"]=>
    string(17) "TEST STOCK LEVELS"
    ["ERROR"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["PROPERTIES"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "1122"
      }
    }
    ["PROPERTIES_INFO"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(12) {
        ["USAGE_TYPE"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["CONTROL"]=>
        string(7) "LISTBOX"
        ["TYPE"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(11) "TEST OPTION"
        ["VALUES"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "1122"
        }
        ["REQUIRED"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["PARENT_PROPERTY_ID"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["PARENT_VALUE_ID"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["TEXT"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["CONTROL_PRICE"]=>
        int(0)
        ["ORDER"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["QUANTITY_ACTION"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["PROPERTIES_PRICE"]=>
    float(10)
    ["PROPERTIES_PERCENTAGE"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_BUYING"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_DISCOUNT"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_MORE"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["COMPONENTS"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["QUANTITY"]=>
    int(11)
    ["TAX_FREE"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["DISCOUNT"]=>
    int(1)
    ["BUYING_PRICE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["PRICE_EDIT"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["PRICE"]=>
    string(5) "10.00"
    ["CHECK_PRICE"]=>
    float(20)
    ["MAX_ITEM_DISCOUNT"]=>
    float(20)
    ["CART_PRICE"]=>
    float(20)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(23) {
    ["ITEM_ID"]=>
    int(2331)
    ["ITEM_TYPE_ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["CART_ITEM_ID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["SAVED_TYPE_ID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ITEM_NAME"]=>
    string(17) "TEST STOCK LEVELS"
    ["ERROR"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["PROPERTIES"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "1123"
      }
    }
    ["PROPERTIES_INFO"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(12) {
        ["USAGE_TYPE"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["CONTROL"]=>
        string(7) "LISTBOX"
        ["TYPE"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(11) "TEST OPTION"
        ["VALUES"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "1123"
        }
        ["REQUIRED"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["PARENT_PROPERTY_ID"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["PARENT_VALUE_ID"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["TEXT"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["CONTROL_PRICE"]=>
        int(0)
        ["ORDER"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["QUANTITY_ACTION"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["PROPERTIES_PRICE"]=>
    float(20)
    ["PROPERTIES_PERCENTAGE"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_BUYING"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_DISCOUNT"]=>
    int(0)
    ["PROPERTIES_MORE"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["COMPONENTS"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["QUANTITY"]=>
    int(5)
    ["TAX_FREE"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["DISCOUNT"]=>
    int(1)
    ["BUYING_PRICE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["PRICE_EDIT"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["PRICE"]=>
    string(5) "10.00"
    ["CHECK_PRICE"]=>
    float(30)
    ["MAX_ITEM_DISCOUNT"]=>
    float(30)
    ["CART_PRICE"]=>
    float(30)
  }
}
```

Before looping this array, I receive some property_id (1123 for example).
I need to check if this property_id matches this element (1122 in my case)

```
["PROPERTIES"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "1122"
      }
    }
```

then select its quantity property (in my case it is this element)

```
 ["QUANTITY"]=>
int(11)
```

The problem is to identify from which arrays select this property, because first I need to compare my received value with existing in array(1122 in my case).

Comment: `str_replace($thisPost, 'massive', 'array')`...? Babelfish?

Comment: i dont get it, can you further specify your problem

Comment: I`ll try. I have some property_id (1122 for ex). And I have 2 arrays. I need to determine in what array this value(1122) matches this value
["PROPERTIES"]=>
    array(1) {
      [522]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "1122"
      }
    }
And, if the matches found, I need to select from this array this value (["QUANTITY"]=>
int(11))

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it faster with a better organized array. As it is I'll do a loop.

Something like that :

```
 $quantity = 0;
 $which_array = -1;
 foreach($massive as $key=>$value){

   if(isset($value['PROPERTIES_INFO'])){
     $copy_properties = $value['PROPERTIES_INFO'];
     $property_first = reset($copy_properties);
     $id_property = key($property_first);
     if($id_property == $what_id_you_are_looking_for){
       $quantity = $value['QUANTITY'];//delete one of this
       //or I don't know wich quantity you want so I put them both
       $quantity = $value['PROPERTIES_INFO'][$id_property ]['QUANTITY_ACTION'];//delete one of this
       $which_array = $key;
       break;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This code show me null for $quantity, unfortunately(

Comment: If u copied pasted this code $quantity cannot be null. plus you have to set $what_id_you_are_looking_for = //something like 1122 in order to work